# twitter bootstrap input-group-addon and btn-group not aligning nicely

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select item that I've applied the selectpicker function on from 
http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ 
now I'm trying to align the input-group-addon with the select, which turned into a btn-group,
however the addon's height is never the same as the btn-group's height, I'm using twitter bootstrap 3. 
Anyone who can advice me on how to do this, my code is:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span id="contact_servicecode" class="input-group-addon ng-binding">CONTACT_SERVICECODE</span>
    <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select">
        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-custom" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
            <div class="filter-option pull-left">1</div>
            <div class="caret"></div>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu open">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu">
        </div>
        <select class="selectpicker mobile-device" style="display: none;">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dzhz4/2/ problem is this shows it how I want it :/

Comment: I just tried it with creating the button group myself and it does what I want, so this must be an issue with the jquery plugin. I'll do it without it

Comment: Make sure you haven't made any changes to the CSS to effect those elements, also use some form of web dev debug tool e.g inbuilt inspect element in chrome, firefox or IE 11.

Comment: @J.Pip I'm having the same problem - can you explain your solution creating the button group? And/or did you figure out how to resolve the jquery issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is my jsbin for how I fixed it.** [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kivopuwe/2/edit)

When you set the input-group sizes either 'input-group-lg' or 'input-group-sm' it will give you predefined sizes - most notably a height of 46px or 30px for the inputs respectively. However nothing happens if you accept the regular size. I think this is so you aren't surprised if you have settings for inputs outside of Bootstrap.

Here are example measurements for lg

```
.input-group-lg > .input-group-btn > .btn {
    height: 46px;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.33;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Instead of tweaking lg after the fact, I created a class called 'input-group-reg' uses measurements that are a middle ground between the 'lg' and 'sm' given by bootstrap.

```
.input-group-reg > .form-control {
    height: 38px;
    padding: 8px 13px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.44;
    border-radius: 6px;  
}

/* Sizing the input */
.default-input-group-lg > form-control {
    height: 38px;
    padding: 8px 13px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.44;
    border-radius: 6px;  
}

/* Sizing the button */
.input-group-reg > .input-group-btn > .btn, .input-group-reg > .input-group-btn:last-child > .dropdown-toggle{
    height: 38px;
    padding: 8px 13px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.44;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're running into a known issue with Bootstrap when it's compiled with some SASS compilers.  See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/409.

If you're using bootstrap-sass, that's that's causing it.  You have to set the SASS precision to 10 before compiling Bootstrap.  How you set it depends on what your particular set up is (Gulp, Grunt, Laravel Elixir, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group[class*="span"]{float:none;display:inline-block;margin-bottom:**0px**;margin-left:0}
```

is on first line of select.min.css
setting margin-botton to 0 ->problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

As @theptrk says, it seems an explicit height isn't being set for buttons in input groups when not using `input-group-sm` or `input-group-lg`. I was able to fix this by just adding this to my bootstrap overrides:

```
// Fix input-group button sizing issue
.input-group > .input-group-btn > .btn, .input-group-btn:last-child > .dropdown-toggle {
  height: 34px;
}
```